# Regex does not work for replacing blank character

Tags: javascript

I want to replace all blank characters :

```
var immatriculation = " 31595 WWT  ";
var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile('test_george.txt', immatriculation.replace(/ /g, ""), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

At runtime I get " 31595WWT "; as you can see there are still the blank characters at the beginning and at the end.

So what is wrong ?

Comment: Trim. You want trim. It's a JS string function.

Comment: trim wouldn't get the space in the middle.

Comment: Can't reproduce, I ran your code and it removes all spaces without issue.

Comment: Your regex seems fine, you could also try to use `/\s/g`. `\s` means "any whitespace character"

Comment: @Reyno make it as answer cause it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex seems fine, you could also try to use `/\s/g`. `\s` means "any whitespace character"

```js
var immatriculation = " 31595 WWT  ";

var result = immatriculation.replace(/\s/g, "");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: so why it needs the `\s` ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as expected:

```js
const str = '   Hello World   ';
console.log(str.replace(/ /g,''));
```

Comment: Yeap! I wonder if fs.writeFIle is adding all the whitespaces

Comment: No, it s for debugging purpose, but the real case does not need any fs.writeFile

Comment: Can you replicate your problem on a codesandbox? Seems like that the part of the code you shared is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replaceAll` method.

```js
var input = " 31595 WWT  ";
console.log(input.replaceAll(" ", ""));
```